# Trouble with own macro

Tags: macros

I'm not sure where my error is. I uses this code:

```
\newcommand{\qr}[2]{%
  \begin{pspicture}(1.378in, 1.5in)%
    \psbarcode[]{#1}{height=1.378 width=1.378}{qrcode}%
    {\psset{unit=1.378in}\rput(0.165,0.165){\color{white}#2}}%
  \end{pspicture}%
}
```

The definition seems to be okay.

In this full example

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, parskip]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\newcommand{\qr}[2]{%
  \begin{pspicture}(1.378in, 1.5in)%
    \psbarcode[]{#1}{height=1.378 width=1.378}{qrcode}%
    {\psset{unit=1.378in}\rput(0.165,0.165){\color{white}#2}}%
  \end{pspicture}%
}

\begin{document}
  \section{Demo}
  \qr{1,1}
\end{document}
```

I get a strange error:

```
! Extra \endgroup. \endpspicture ->\pst@killglue \endgroup
                                         \egroup \ifdim \wd \pst@hbox =\z@ \e... l.57   \end{pspicture}
```

What does this mean and how to avoid that?

Comment: Did you try writing `\qr{1}{1}`, which is the correct way to pass two arguments?

Comment: Oh god how painful. That works!

Comment: In the last sentence I linked the full latex code. I'll add it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your command receives two mandatory arguments, so you have to use

```
\qr{1}{1}
```

Comment: @rekire: No problem ;-)

Answer (score 8):

If you must (or want to) specify the parameters in that specific (comma-separated) format, you should use something similar to this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-barcode

\newcommand{\qr}[1]{\qrbase(#1)}
\def\qrbase(#1,#2){%
  \begin{pspicture}(1.378in, 1.5in)%
    \psbarcode[]{#1}{height=1.378 width=1.378}{qrcode}%
    {\psset{unit=1.378in}\rput(0.165,0.165){\color{white}#2}}%
  \end{pspicture}%
}

\begin{document}
  \section{Demo}
  \qr{1,1}
\end{document}​
```

[image]

However, it is easier to use @Gonzalo's approach.